# grafana variable regex : grouping for name and value

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

My grafana uses a mysql datasource.
A table WORK contains a column id (numeric) and wname (work name, varchar).
My variable $wo has this query :

```
select concat ("WORK ", wname, ", work-", id) from work order by wname
```

A single row example is

```
WORK-painting, work-722
```

I would like to set the text of $wo to WORK-painting and its value to work-722.
I use the regex :

```
/(?<text>.*),(?<value>.*)/
```

The button run-query valorize the section "Preview of values" with :

```
WORK-painting  WORK-playing etc ./..
```

Where are my values work-id ? And when I use the variable $wo in a panel, I still get the name instead of the value. Help please :)

Comment: 1. Don't use regex here. Simply return columns `__text` and `__value` as described [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/#query-variable)

Comment: 2. Preview doesn't show values, only names. To check value you'll need to use variable somewhere (in panel name, for example). `$var` should be enough, but you can also check `${var:value}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not well defined in the documentation
You can access the value with this syntax :

```
${variable_name:raw}
```